# Overview of Test outcome connected to test suite and tester in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, test-suite, test-plan, test-results

I would like to get a simple overview, preferably some kind of list, of the test results (manual tests) connected to the test suite and who performed the test. The test plan summary in the "Enhanced test suite export" is the closest i have been able to get, but without the tester. Is it possible to get it in a list view or in an excel export instead?

I would like to get something like this:
[image: Excel table]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but as I know we don't have such out-of-box feature to generate the Test report above.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Also you can use rest api [Test Point - Get Points List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20point/get%20points%20list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to list the `test points` with given `Test Plan ID` and `Test Suite ID`, the response would also contain the `tester` information.